# Crontab: zip: command not found

Tags: bash

I have the following script that runs perfectly when I execute it:

```
#!/bin/bash
zip logs.zip -r *
```

However when I run it from crontab, i get

```
/home/ubuntu/script.sh: line 2: zip: command not found
```

Why is that? Do I need to set up some sort of path? I have no luck searching for it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your login shell will have zip in the PATH, however cron will not run commands in a login shell. You can specify environment variables in your crontab file, you should probably set the PATH to the same as your login shell and possibly add some more variables too. I have:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
MAILTO="my@email.address"
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

So that cron runs bash, sends emails to a working address and uses a decent PATH

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to find full path of zip

```
which zip
```

then use full path is your script... ie:

```
/usr/bin/zip logs.zip -r *
```

Comment: you should probably also cd to the right directory or use full path for the * (i.e. /usr/bin/zip /home/pear/logs.zip /var/log/*)

Comment: `which` is suboptimal -- it's an external tool that searches the PATH; its results aren't guaranteed to be identical to what your shell is using (if you have aliases, shell functions, cached prior PATH lookups, etc). `type zip` is the built-in equivalent in bash, or `command -v zip` for all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: (Also, embedding fully-qualified names in your cron-referenced scripts makes those scripts less portable to other machines, whereas setting a `PATH` at the top of your crontab means that you're doing machine-specific customization in only one place).